# Ordering of Joomla Plugins

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have two plugins, one of type 'system' and other of type say 'xyz'. I would like to make xyz have higher priority than the system plugin. Is it possible? In Joomla Plugin manager, I see that the priority can be changed only with in the plugin types.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as system plugin has highest priority in Joomla. So you need to make your plugin as system plugin and then you can change the ordering of Plugin.

Answer (score -1):

> The ordering of the system plugins is almost always the key to solving
>   these problems. Plugins are executed in the order they have in the
>   Plugin Manager (under menu 'Extension' in the Joomla! administrator
>   side).

Read more here:
[Plugin order importance](https://www.regularlabs.com/blog/242-plugin-order-is-important)

Hope this can be helpful about joomla plugins execution order.